# Can I resize QTWidgets when QTMainWindow grows without layout management?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, resize, mainwindow

I have searched on the internet for a long time but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

When resizing the main window of my application I want some of my widgets to grow.

A lot of answers I found were about using layout managers.

My application was almost done so if I use a horizontal or vertical layout my application looks completely different from what it looks now and I am not able to change it to the way it was.

Does anybody know if you can resize widgets while resizing the mainwindow without using layout managers?

Comment: you can override [`resizeEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) in your main window, and resize your widgets however you like there. But layout managers are the right tool to do this. layouts are not limited to vertical and horizontal layouts, there are forms and grid layouts, you can also have all of these nested in some way. . .

Comment: Btw, if you want to use layouts, you should learn what `QSizePolicy` is and how it works with layouts.